# Does DigestInputStream in a try-with-resources close the original InputStream?

Tags: java, stream, try-catch

Do I need to explicitly close the original `InputStream` if I declared a `DigestInputStream` in a try-with-resources block?

Example:

```
InputStream is = ...;
MessageDigest md = ...;

try (final DigestInputStream digestInputStream = new DigestInputStream(is, md)) {
    // Read the stream...
}
```

Do I need to close is manually or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `DigestInputStream` is an `AutoCloseable` you don't need to close it manually when you declared it in a try-with-resources block.

Docu from `AutoCloseable`:

> The {@link #close()} method of an {@code AutoCloseable}
>   object is called automatically when exiting a {@code
>   try}-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in
>   the resource specification header.

In addition, the `FilterInputStream` overrides the`close` method which closes the used `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

No. It will be closed automatically.

Here is source code from `java.io.FilterInputStream`:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    in.close();
}
```